# Unit test for EJB with @PostConstruct method

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, mockito

Consider the following sample code:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {

  private SomeHelper helper;

  private long someField;

  @PostConstruct
  void init() {
    helper = new SomeHelper();

    someField = initSomeField();
  }

  long initSomeField() {
    // perform initialization
  }

  public void methodToTest() {
    helper.someMethod();
    long tmp = 3 + someField;
  }

}
```

And here is the test template, that I always use

```
public class MyBeanTest {

  @Spy
  @InjectMocks
  private MyBean testSubject;

  @Mock
  private SomeHelper mockedHelper;

  @Before
  public void before() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    doReturn(1L).when(testSubject).initSomeField();
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    testSubject.methodToTest();
    // assertions
  }

}
```

The problem with testing `methodToTest` is that it needs field `someField` to be initialized. But the initialization is done in `@PostConstruct` method. And I can't run this method before call to `testSubject.methodToTest()`, because it will re-initialize `helper`. Also, I don't want to manually set up all the mocks. And I don't want to use reflection to set the `someField`, because that would make `MyBeanTest` vulnerable to `MyBean` refactoring. Can anybody propose, maybe better design to avoid situations like this?

A few notes:

Logic in `initSomeField` could be quite heavy (including calls to database), so I want to initialize it only once in a `@PostConstruct` method.

I don't want to create a setter for this field or widen its access modifier, because that would allow unwanted changes to my field.

Answer (score 1):

If your test is in the same package as your class, then you can just call `initSomeField` directly, since it's package private.  You can either do this in each individual test method, or in your `@Before` method, provided it runs after `initMocks`.

Comment: At first, it looked obvious. But then I recalled, that `initSomeField` is not a setter. It just returns a value, but doesn't set `someField` to anything. I realize that it's probably something wrong with the code design, and willing to rewrite it, but have hot yet figured out how. Thanks for your input, anyway.

Comment: So where is the actual code that you need to run to do the initialisation part?  So long as your `testSubject` is properly initialised, I don't see what would stop your test from working.

Comment: The method `initSomeField` doesn't initialize the field. I chose the misleading name. It simply returns a value, which is then assigned in the `@PostConstruct` to the field. Yes, one way to refactor would be to move field initialization to the `initSomeField` method, but that reduces code readability... So, probably I should go with reflection, after all.

Comment: I still don't see why you need reflection.  Can't you just call `init()` within your test code?

Comment: But doing so will corrupt the state of `MyBean` mock. There are much more services being initialized before `someField`. And they're all mocked using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`. But if I call `init` directly, then I'll have to set up all the mocks manually.

Comment: So this is actually an integration test of a whole load of different classes?  You're not keen on testing those services separately, then mocking them here?

Comment: No, this is unit test. And I **do** want to mock those services here. That's why I don't want to call init directly, which will erase all the mocks set up by Mockito.